# Chrome Bookmarks vanished after clearing history!

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, google-chrome, bookmarks

I recently cleared my history from Google Chrome because of stupid MacKeeper ads, whenever I try to click on any site the new window bars open which was MacKeeper or another ad.
I was sick of it and cleared my history and unfortunately when I reopen my Chrome all my bookmarks have gone. I am so disappointed. I searched everywhere and tried everything but still I am getting these ads and no bookmarks have come back.
They said
"Here's where the Chrome bookmarks and the backup are located:
`Macintosh HD/Users/your user name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks`"

I tried to reach there but I didn't find any folder of Chrome or Google in my apps even Chrome is installed in my Mac and working fine.
Please, can any one help me out!
I didn't backup been ages :'(. I hope it is stored here some where.
Using Macbook Pro Yosemite

Answer (score 2):

Try this to see if you're just looking in the wrong place...

Quit Chrome
Switch to Finder
Open a new Finder window,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd> 
Go To...  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd> 
Copy/paste this `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/` (including the tilde ~) into that Go To window
Hit Enter

What do you see?

Bookmarks ought to be in there, along with Bookmarks.bak
Hold  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  & drag both to the desktop, for safety.
Delete Bookmarks.
Rename Bookmarks.bak to Bookmarks
Launch Chrome

BTW, ~ (tilde) is Mac shorthand for your home folder, in `My hard drive/my user name/` without needing to know what they are called. It always goes to *your* home folder.

Comment: I tried this, where it put this ~??

Comment: where what puts what?

Comment: I tried to put Tilde ~ at the beginning nothing happened and then tried at the end nothing happened as well. No any new window opened! Even with out tilde~ nothing happened! :(

Comment: just copy/paste, don't try to type it by hand. ***Something*** will always happen, even if it's an error. If you get an error, post it exactly as written.

Comment: sorry, I left the tilde out of my copy/paste line, my bad. Fixed

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happened when I copy paste. You didn't tell me where to put tilde ~ !!!

Comment: Nothing happened. copy pasted this ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/

Comment: Something must happen, it will either take that new window to the correct location or beep & tell you it doesn't exist

Comment: Ok I went to these folders by my self and found it in this folder /chrome/profile1 I didn't find any default folder there

Comment: question is you said to hold alt key and drag both folder I think you wanna say hold cmd key. Any way I put in desktop and deleted bookmarks folder and rename bookmarks.bak to bookmarks. Now I should put it back where I drag them out from. or should I leave it on desktop?

Comment: I put it back and relaunch chrome. It was newest bookmarks. Not the old ones. Tell me where can I find old bookmarks!!! There is no default folder in there!

Comment: I did mean Alt, to copy in case something went wrong, Cmd will move not copy. The reason there was no default is because at some time you have set up user profiles, which I've no experience with. Time to see what you have backed up in Time Machine, I guess